# How can I get an entries author custom field?

Tags: users

I have a custom field for a user which is an asset, it has the users larger profile photo.

In an entry template I can get their profile photo using:

```
{{ entry.author.getPhotoUrl }}
```

But I want to get the custom field.

Something like:

```
{{ entry.author.authorImage }}
```

I am sure I am missing something very simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer with a `for` loop works but if you know there's only one image associated with that field, you can simplify your code using `.first()`:

```
    <img src="{{ entry.author.authorImage|length ? entry.author.authorImage.first().getUrl() : '/images/userprofiledefault.jpg' }}" alt="{{ entry.author.getFullName }}">
```

Think of assets (and relationships in general) as a [container](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets-fields#templating) that can hold more than one asset (or relationship). That's why you need to tell Craft *which* one you want—even if there's only one. Your `for` loop works because it's looping through that object (technically an ElementCriteriaModel object).

Comment: Ah perfect. Thanks for that. Will swap it out for that.

Comment: @Gary when using first you should check if it does return an asset model before accessing one of its properties!

Comment: Good thought carlcs, updated my answer to include a fallback image.

Answer (score 1):

Ah it would of been handy if I had of entered the assets loop!

```
  {% for asset in entry.author.authorImage %}
    <img src="{{ asset.getUrl() }}" alt="{{ entry.author.getFullName }}">
  {% endfor %}
```